# Menu mmenu not displaying with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery UI for autocomplete with jQuery mobile. But in presence of these 2 libraries `.mmenu` displays nothing.

I create menu by using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mmenu = $("#mcba-menu").mmenu({}).data('mmenu');
  $('a').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    mmenu.open();
  });
});
```

My header is:

```
<head>
  <title>MCBA</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico"></link>
  <link href="./resources/css/jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/jquery/jquery.mobile- 1.4.5.min.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/3rdparty/hamburger.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css"></link>
  <script src="./resources/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="./resources/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
  <script src="./resources/js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./resources/js/component.js"></script>
  <script src="./resources/js/custome.js"></script>
        <script src="http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js?v=5.2.0"></script> 
</head>
```

Body code is:

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="#mcba-menu"></a>
                FLIGHT TRANSFER
</div>
<nav id="mcba-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
</nav>
```

![result page ][1]

Comment: are you really loading the mmenu js file? I mean is it available when your are debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your body code, use `div` tag instead of `nav`. As given below

```
<div id="mcba-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this link for loading the file:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.3.1/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js

So instead of

```
<script src="http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js?v=5.2.0"></script>
```

You would have:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.3.1/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
```